# use iphone camera to record video on to a computer

Tags: video, pc, video-capture

I have a Windows 7 PC and an iPhone 5s with iOS 8.0.2. I would like to use the video camera functionality of the iPhone to record a lengthy (over 6 hours) video. The phone can be connected to my computer the whole time so I would like to avoid using the phone memory and rather use the computer HD (since the phone will run out of memory). How can this be done?

Comment: where you able to find an answer?

Comment: unfortunately i was not